# cl-actors return value

Tags: multithreading, lisp, common-lisp, actor

This may be a stupid question, or at least one with some incorrect assumptions about the actors model, but perhaps someone could educate me. Suppose I set up an example actor similar to one found in the [cl-actors](https://github.com/naveensundarg/Common-Lisp-Actors) example documentation

```
cl-user> (ql:quickload :cl-actors)
:CL-ACTORS

cl-user> (use-package :cl-actors)
T

cl-user> (defactor echo (stream) (message) 
           (format stream "~a~%" message)
           next)
ECHO

cl-user> (defparameter e (echo :stream *standard-output*))
E

cl-user> (send e "Test message")
Test Message
; No value
```

Why is there `; No value` there instead of `NIL`? Is there a way to get the returned value out without killing the actor thread with`(bt:join-thread (cl-actors::get-thread e))` (which I suspect wouldn't exactly do what I want in any case)? I'm specifically looking to get the return value, and not play tricks with `with-output-to-string` or similar.

The more general problem I'm trying to solve, in case you care, is trying to output information from an actor into a `cl-who` page for the client side. Something along the lines of

```
(with-html-output (s)
   (:h1 (send e "Test message")))
```

which clearly won't work if `send` doesn't return anything. Pointers on the more general problem are welcome if the specific question actually proves to be stupid.

Comment: @wvxvw - Yup; that's why I put in the note about the more general problem I'm trying to solve; having a bunch of actors interacting is fine, but I'm trying to hook a network of them up to Hunchentoot (an HTTP server which is not an actor, so `send`ing messages to it isn't a solution). I'm beginning to get the feeling that I ought to just write a quick actors-based server if I wanted to do something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing cl-actors slightly and adding a `send-receive` construct that does what I want in this situation. The modified code is [here](https://github.com/Inaimathi/Common-Lisp-Actors) (comments encouraged). The core is this:

```
(defmethod send-receive ((self actor) message &optional (timeout 0))
  (let ((tmp (make-queue)))
    (send self tmp message)
    (car (dequeue tmp timeout))))
```

Essentially, we declare a temporary queue, send a message with that queue as a receiver, then try to pop a value off it with an optional timeout (`0` means `wait forever`). This depends on the target actor accepting a `sender` parameter, which seems like a sufficiently `actors`y way to go about it..

Answer (score 0):

You pass the stream (`*STANDARD-OUTPUT*`) to your actor and get the string printed to that stream. If you pass your web request output stream, you'll get the string printed there. If you want to return the data to the calling actor to do something with it, you should pass its id and send the data back to it.